# What tools provide hooks for transforming JSON to model class objects?

Tags: objective-c, json, code-generation, restkit

I can easily find tools that:

- transform JSON to csharp model classes
- transform JSON to objc model classes
- transform JSON to POJOs for java
- etc.

But what happens if I'm looking to step in the middle of this process and roll my own transformer from JSON to `blah` model classes?

Is there a programming framework or tool that understands JSON very well and simply provides hooks or callbacks that I can programmatically implement, in order to do the second half of the job, which is to spit out my own style of model classes?

My motivation behind this question is the fact that I found: http://jsonpack.com/ModelGenerators/ObjectiveC which helps generate ObjC model classes which are dependent on the JSONKit framework but I would like to generate ObjC model classes that are dependent on the RestKit framework instead.

Comment: Writing your own generic transformer code would be easier than hooking existing code.

Comment: If I hear back from folks about tools and frameworks whose quality is poor, I will be sure to roll my own from scratch and share it too. I always prefer to evaluate what exists in the community first because with time and visibility bugs always decrease in any code.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for a "SAX style" parser. That is, you implement some sort of a *delegate* for a parser which receives *parse events* from the parser and which handles these events appropriately.

So, instead of creating a JSON representation which is a hierarchy of Foundation objects consisting of NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSString etc., your delegate instead creates one or more instances of certain custom classes.

While this is feasible, if you have such a "SAX style" parser (which NSJSONSerialization is not), it certainly requires some amount of effort. Note, that you can always "convert" a Foundation hierarchy to any other object - say a Core Data model object. (Means, initialize an object from a NSDictionary). But, the more elaborate approach is certainly faster.

The two Objective-C JSON parser frameworks that I know of which have a SAX style API are SBJson https://github.com/stig/json-framework/ and JPJson https://github.com/couchdeveloper/JPJson.

The latter parser library (JPJson) is in fact quite obviously designed by separating these two tasks: a) parsing and b) performing semantic actions. You can subclass from an existing base class "semantic actions" "and create your own and override "handler methods" which correspond to handle the parse events.

I'm the author of JPJson and currently updating it to accommodate for new clang compiler (C++11) and Xcode.